# Haskell socket action invocation syntax

Tags: sockets, haskell, syntax

In the code snippet `s <- socket :: IO (Socket Inet Stream TCP)` what does the sub-expression starting with "::" mean?

I can understand when "::" is used in a function signature as in `socket :: (Family f, Type t, Protocol  p) => IO (Socket f t p)`, but not when "::" is used in the action invocation as in this case.

This is as listed in the example code at [the Haskell socket manual](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-0.5.2.0/docs/System-Socket.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only really means "take this expression to produce this type". Convoluted? Not really, consider

```
x = 0
```

What type is x of? `Num a => a`. What if you wanted specifically an `Int`?

```
x = 0 :: Int
```

That's all there is to it. It's not specific to sockets at all, it's a part of standard Haskell syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly helps me understand so will accept the solution.